# Python: ftplib slow on upload

Tags: python, performance, upload, ftplib

I am having problems with the python script I am running on my Raspberry Pi.  When I get to a 'ftp.storbinary' line the upload takes longer than when just in a simple upload program.

I was wondering if there is a command that would start the upload, but continue to the next line of script as the file was uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multi-threading. Here is a link to a tutorial for multi-threading programming in python.

[Python Multi-Threading Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm)